# La variable esta asignada pero no se usa su valor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows

Como dice el titulo tengo una variable declarada a nivel de clase pero me da ese mensaje pero si lo uso.

```
public partial class TextBoxUniversal : TextBox
{
    private bool Sombra;
    private bool _mTeclaPermitida = true; Mensaje de advertencia
    //private string separafecha = "/";

    private Font oldFont = null;
    private Boolean waterMarkTextEnabled = false;

   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const Int32 emUndo = 0xc7;// Es el mensaje Deshacer para los controles TextBox de una única línea.
        const Int32 wmClear = 0x303;
        const Int32 wmCopy = 0x301;
        const Int32 wmCut = 0x300;
        const Int32 wmPaste = 0x0302;
        const Int32 wmUndo = 0x304;// Es el mensaje Deshacer para los controles TextBox multilínea.

        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case wmClear:
                _mTeclaPermitida = true;

                break;
            case wmCopy:
                _mTeclaPermitida = true;

                break;
            case wmCut:
                _mTeclaPermitida = true;

                break;
            case wmPaste:
                var dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                if (dataObject != null && !(dataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)))
                    return;

                // Comprobamos si el contenido del portapapeles es numérico.
                if ((!(ValidateClipboardText())))
                {
                    _mTeclaPermitida = false;
                    return;
                }

                _mTeclaPermitida = true;

                break;
            case emUndo:
                _mTeclaPermitida = true;

                break;
            case wmUndo:
                _mTeclaPermitida = true;

                break;
        }

        // Procesamos los restantes mensajes
        base.WndProc(ref m);

    }
```

Como puedo corregir para que no me de ese mensaje?

Comment: cual es la variable que marca el problema?

Comment: Leandro el mensaje sale en donde declaro la variable.

Comment: en que contexto defines esa variable, edita el codigo y especifica la clase y donde pones ese codigo

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta ahi indico donde sale el mensaje

Comment: @PedroÁvila ¿y sigue saliendo? Si deseas eliminar las `advertencias` también puedes en Visual Studio abrir la ventana `Error List` y da clic al botón `Warnings` (que se encuentra al lado de la cantidad de errores). En todo caso, la respuesta de Leandro es la respuesta correcta.

Comment: en realidad edita la pregunta y define el class para ver donde ubicas la variable respecto al metodo

Comment: Ya volví a modificar haber fijate

Comment: no veo nada incorrecto en el codigo, salvo que cuando escibes "Mensaje de advertencia" si lo has puesto en el codigo te falta las // del comentario

Comment: 1>D:\Programas de Desarrollo\Text01082016CorreciónCombo\TextBox\TextBoxUniversal.cs(20,22,20,38): warning CS0414: El campo 'TextBoxUniversal._mTeclaPermitida' está asignado pero su valor nunca se usa

Comment: Leandro, declarando la variable como protected o publica no da error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que debes asignar un valor por defecto a la variable cuando al declaras

```
private bool _mTeclaPermitida = true;
```

a veces buscar el mensaje en ingles ayuda

[Compiler Warning (level 3) CS0414](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z62k595w.aspx)

Comment: Hola Leandro, al asignarle true a la variable, debería borrar los true en el resto del código?, igual me sigue dando el mensaje!!!

Comment: en que linea marca el problema ?

Comment: Donde declaro la variable.

Comment: que variable ? estas mencionando que tienes un mensaje de error, pero no especificas donde lo marca

Comment: El mensaje sale en donde declaro la variable a nivel de clase private bool _mTeclaPermitida;

Comment: Esto puede pasar por que no en todos los caminos del switch asignas valor a la variable.